# Find $x$ in terms of $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A survey of $n$ people found that $60$ % preferred brand $A$. An additional $x$ people were surveyed who all preferred brand $A$. $70$% of all people surveyed preferred brand $A$ . Find $x$ in terms of $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

So, initially $60$% of $n$ i.e., $n\cdot \frac{60}{100}=\frac{3n}5$ people preferred brand $A$

So, the total people preferring brand $A$ is $\frac{3n}5+x$ which is the $70$% of all the people $n+x$

$$\implies \frac{3n}5+x=\frac{70}{100}\cdot\left(n+x\right)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I tried to solve but i found following last equation $3x/10 = 2n/5$

Comment: @SSK, $$ \frac{3n}5+x=\frac{70}{100}\cdot\left(n+x\right)\implies 60x+100n=70x+70n\implies (100-70)x=(70-60)n\implies n=3x$$

Comment: $60x+100n=70x+70n$ can please explain this step in detail ?

Comment: poke to lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @SSK, multiply either side by $100$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that:
$$
(0.60)n + (1.00)x = (0.70)(n+x)
$$
Can you solve for $x$ now? **Spoiler Below:**

> \begin{align*}0.6n+x&=0.7(n+x)\\6n+10x&=7(n+x)\\6n+10x&=7n+7x\\3x&=n\\x&=\dfrac{n}{3}\\\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

out of n people $.60n$ preferred brand $A$

you add x people to the sample making the total sample $(n + x)$

you know that those x people preferred brand $A$

so now the total number of people who prefer $A$ equals $(x + 0.6n)$

$70$% of all people surveyed $(n+x)$ preferred brand $A: 0.7(n + x)$ prefer $A$

so now you get $0.7(n + x) = x + 0.6n$

from here you can get $x$ in terms of $n$